# How to pass data value from Bootstrap Modal to Parent form

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How to pass data attribute or click event from Bootstrap modal to parent form/window.

for example,
On clicking the below input box, the modal will popup with divs having data attribute

```
<input type="text" name="menu_image_id" class="form-control" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".show_modal_w" />

<input type="text" name="menu_image_id_2" class="form-control" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".show_modal_w" />
```

Modal window

```
<div class="modal fade show_modal_w" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div data-id="1"  data-dismiss="modal">Hello</div>
        <div data-id="2"  data-dismiss="modal">Welcome</div>
        <div data-id="3"  data-dismiss="modal">Morning</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now when the user clicks the div inside the modal for example either Hello, Welcome or Morning, then we need to pass the id value from modal to parent input box with name menu_image_id.

I tried using the below close function, but not able to get the modal data id to parent window.

```
$('.show_modal_w').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(e.relatedTarget);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying a different way than you did,

instead of capturing the hidden.bs.modal, I'm capturing the div.on.click, so instead of:

```
$('.show_modal_w').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(e.relatedTarget);
})
```

I wrote

```
$("body").on("click", ".show_modal_w div[data-id]", function() {
    $("input[name='menu_image_id']").val($(this).data("id") + " - " + $(this).text());
    $(".show_modal_w").modal("hide");
});
```

And here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f9urohoo/
I put the id and the text of the div clicked in the input with [name="menu_image_id"] but you can adapt that as you wish.

Tell me if it is what you wanted

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It worked good, the problem am facing is, it always put the value into name=menu_image_id even though if we have multiple name, Is there any way to make the menu_image_id to be dynamic , like we need to capture the on click input name field.

Comment: @Vinoth Kumar I'm non sure to understand what you want exactly, car you explain a typical workflow you want to have  ?

Comment: Yes I have solved it by adding the unique id for each input box [which stores the image id] and pass that value to modal using e.relatedTarget and placed a hidden input box in that modal to store the input box unique key value. Then after clicked the modal div, I have searched the unique key stored in modal hidden box through the body and place the modal div clicked id there. Finally solved :-) Thanks for your great help Gille

Comment: Glad I could help you to find your own way :)